# Splatting args into the AWS cli results in "unknown options"

Tags: powershell, aws-cli, parameter-splatting

I'm getting the error unknown options from this:

```
$test = "s3",  "ls",  "s3://mybucket", '--region us-east-2'
aws @test
```

*Unknown options: --region us-east-2*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the argument with a value needs to be broken up:

'--region us-east-2' to
'--region', 'us-east-2'

```
$test = "s3",  "ls",  "s3://mybucket", '--region', 'us-east-2'
aws @test
```